# React Page showing DOM error of another page

Tags: reactjs

new to react. I was wondering why my React page A was showing query selector error of page B. The error loops like infinite times until I route to Page B.

Code in page B

```
Function update(){

var checkExist = setInterval(function() {

if (('#container').length) {  //if container div exists
let container =  document.querySelectorAll("#container")

let offbutton = container[0].querySelector('#offbutton')

}

   clearInterval(checkExist);
   }
 }, 100);


}
```

Code Update : Cannot use useffect as this is called when inside another function

Comment: Please share a code, so We can understand the issue.

Comment: @jot that’s not the code causing this. Share the code related to the error, other’s that might be related too.

Comment: Yes its showing error in that offbutton

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelector')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
if (('#container').length) {
```

It would return true always. Because the length of the string "#container" is 10, and is truthy.

Please try this

```
let container =  document.querySelectorAll("#container")

if (container && container.length) {
let offbutton = container[0].querySelector('#offbutton')
}
```

Comment: Hey I have updated the question. The problem is that use effect cant be used as its under another function

Comment: How long do you need the timer to run? The ideal solution would be to somehow clear the timer when the component is mounted (unless you need the timer to be run even if the component is not mounted)

Another option is to do a check like this prior to accessing container[0]
```
if(container && container.length) { 
  let offbutton = ....
}
````

Comment: I just want it to run until he container exits, so i can use the DOM query selector.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please give it a shot

Comment: Hey man, more confused now. I made couple more pages to navigate to. The error in pageB doesnot exists in Page A now, but it starts the dom error if i navigate to other pages. No idea why this is happening.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by dom error? It's hard to comment on what could be going wrong without seeing the code and the error details.

In the above scenario, all we did was to do a null check prior to accessing value/properties on the object.
Do you have the code in github/codesandbox?

Comment: I found the issue. The issue is when exiting the page before the clearInterval () is called. So if i wait until the container loads fully , clear interval , then leave the page, there is no problem.

Comment: Good to hear that you figured it out. I would suggest you to refactor this bit (maybe use useEffect) to make sure that this code runs only when the component is mounted and the cleanup happens when it's unmounted.

Comment: ya, i found the issue not the solution yet.  I need to find how to clear that interval even if i leave the page before clear interval is called

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect` hook to run your query selector code after the component is mounted and the DOM is ready.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
    let container = document.querySelectorAll("#container");
    if (container && container.length) {
      let offbutton = container[0].querySelector("#offbutton");
    }
  }, 100);
  return () => clearInterval(checkExist);
}, []);
```

Comment: Hey I have updated the question. The problem is that use effect cant be used as its under another function

Comment: hey, #offbutton is created dynamically? Please share render function.